# How do I write in regex: the previous pattern cannot appear in the rest of the line?

Tags: regex

I would like to match string with different numbers in them separated by text

For example **match** a strings like:
`Hello 42 here is the next number 43`
The numbers can be anything but cannot be the same.

And **not match** a strings like:
`Hello 42 here is the next number 42`
Where the numbers are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
\D+(\d+)\D+(?:(?!\1)\d+)
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/dQ5kX6/3)